# How do I get View ID from Google Analytics 4?

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I tried to retrieve all information about my website from GA (Google Analytics). I'm using laravel and this package https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics to make my life easier. However, that package requires "View ID" from GA, which I can't help myself to find it. I read this thread https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/15684521?hl=en and I'm guessing that since GA 4 they totally removed the views column from Web + App property (which will be created as a default) (correct me pls). Did anyone had this problem before? Where I can find that "view id"? are there some articles that can help me solve this problem? Any suggestion about better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In GA4 there aren't Views so you if you want to use your code (who needs a View), you have to create a Universal Analytics Property.

You can find it by clicking on `Show advanced options` (when you create a new property):

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. Finally found the view id. However I just realized the data latency took 24 hours long from the GA real time to finally fetched to my application. There's nothing I can do with this one. So I decided to use other services like Histat and override their widgets style. Thank you for answering a right answer.

Comment: I'm correcting my comment for those who read it. I was wrong about data latency. I already using histat, but then I feel kinda weird that the data latency took that long, so I decided to try GA once more. So long my die dump returning an empty array, after a couple minutes, it's magically showing the data, which in real-time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a way to get this View ID after a new Analytics property was created?

Comment: There are no views in GA4.

Comment: @Greg if your code forced you to use view id, then you should follow michele answer.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone using GA4, you must use [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) instead of Reporting API. Use the same oauth scopes and you can use already issued token. This is the sample http request (post):

`https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/[property id]:runRealtimeReport`

with example body:

```
{
  "metrics": [{ "name": "activeUsers" }]
}
```

which gives you simple result. Keep in mind that metrics are different, there are now no totalUsers. Use [this list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-api-schema#metrics) which has all allowed metrics and you can find dimensions on the same page.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed after tinkering with the reports API to no avail for hours.