# find view(profile) ID for my project in google analytics V4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Currently, in my project "dev--sci" I do not see a third column with View Settings to get my view ID from (need this to call Google Analytics API).
[image]
I followed the directions from this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64510635/how-do-i-get-view-id-from-google-analytics-4), which called for creating a new universal property. However, this appears to take me out of "dev--sci" altogether and create a new project called "views (UA-XXXXXX)", which does have the View Settings. But I need the view ID for my original "dev--sci" project, not this blank new one.
[image]

How do I get the view ID for my original project "dev--sci" and why doesn't it have the third view column? I believe it's b/c GA V4 doesn't have views, but then for some reason their API still requires it?

Answer (score 2):

As you read in that post, **GA4 does not have views**, so if you are looking for a view ID to be able to use the APIs that require it in GA4, it means that you are using the wrong APIs, i.e. those that work with Universal Analytics (UA-XXXXX- XX).

GA4 uses a completely different data model from that of Google Analytics, for this reason the APIs to be used are different.

Here you can find some information about Google Analytics Data API V1 that provides programmatic methods to access report data in Google Analytics 4 (GA4) properties:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

However, as you can see, this is an early preview version of the API and is subject to change:

[image]